# changed commit message ok in gitlog but not in github

Tags: git, github

I followed the steps from [Change old commit message on Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884474/change-old-commit-message-on-git), and I confirmed the commit message updated in `git log`. But when I click the "Commit History" tab in Github, I still see the old message and old SHA-1.

So, I blindly tried `git push origin master`, but that failed with:

```
To git@github.com:foobar.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:foobar.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

The error tells me to "merge with remote changes before pushing again", but that seems like the wrong thing to do: merging new stuff into an amended commit (from an older base). I'm confused.

How can I commit my amended message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are rewriting history, you need to call:

```
git push --force
```

Answer (score 1):

As @xsace says, you are rewriting history here.

A commit in git is linked to several things:

- the commit metadata (author, committer, timestamps, commit message);
- the parent commit (or commit_s_ if it is a merge);
- the tree.

If you change any of these, and you did here (you changed the commit message), your history and github's (or any other remote's for that matter) diverge:

```
[parent]----[master@github]
    \
     \------[your local master]
```

Here, you want to push `yourlocalmaster` to github, but this is not a *fast forward*, ie the current master head at github is not an immediate parent to your commit. Therefore you need to force the push.

This can also be done with `git push github +master`.