# MINGW64 (Git Bash) interactive rebase opening a bizarre version of Vim?

Tags: git, vim, vi, mingw-w64

I'm running MINGW64 on Windows 10. I'd like to change the names of some of my previous Git commits a la [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1884582/5549431). Git's been working great so far, and I can also run Vi/Vim through MINGW64 with no issues whatsoever.

The problems begin when I enter the command `git rebase -i HEAD~1`. I get this bizarre version of vim that doesn't seem to respond well to traditional Vim input. I hit the `Esc` key to navigate with arrows or with `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l`. But instead of navigating, it either overwrites existing characters with A, B, C, D (if using arrow keys) or with the characters h, j, k, and l.

Even using the traditional save/quit commands is bizarre. I hit `Esc :` and nothing appears at the bottom of the screen. I hit `q!`, and they appear in the text file, overwriting still more characters. I hit `Enter` and the file does quit without saving, so the functionality is correct, but there was no feedback on the screen to let me know that I would be successful.

I checked both my global `.gitconfig` file and my local `config` file (both of which I can edit just fine in Vim), and both of them have `[core] editor` set to `vi`.

Does anyone know what's going on? I've scoured the web for possible options that I need to add to my config files that might be needed, but I'm not seeing anything that looks like it will fix the problem.

Comment: `:echo $VIM` in the good and the bad case. It is not the same : git is using the mingw64'sbusybox vi. In my opignon